# jQuery - Delays the fetching of new messages

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have coded a chat app. Everything works fine. But I'm having some delayed response.

Code:

```
var lastMsgID = '0';

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submitmsg").click(function(){   
        var clientmsg = $("#usermsg").val();

        $.post("jqpost.php", {usermsg: clientmsg });                
        $("#usermsg").attr("value", "");
        return false;
    });

    setTimeout (poll, 500);
    //poll();
}
);

function poll(){
$.ajax({ 
    url: "jq.php", 
    type: "GET",
    data: "mid=" + lastMsgID,
    dataType: "json",  
    async: true,  
    cache: false,  
    timeout: 30000,  
    complete: poll,

    success: function(data){  
        //we got the msgs and will be displaying it... and update the variable 'lastMsgID' with the last id

 }}
);
}
```

Server side(PHP):
                //query the db
                $result = $mysqli->query($sql);

```
    $wait_start = time();
    $wait_current = 0;
    while ($wait_current < 20 && $result->num_rows == 0)
    {
        usleep(200000); // 0.2 seconds
        $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
        $wait_current = time() - $wait_start;
    }


    if($result->num_rows > 0)
    {
                    //echo the new msgs...
            }
```

The problem is, when I send a message, it would take about 9 to 15 seconds to receive it(along with any new msgs) via the polling.

I have checked with Firebug and found that the POST to "jqpost.php" is showing a loading icon and at the same time the GET request made by poll() is also showing the loading icon.
I think, they are in synchronous mode or waiting for the response. But the $.ajax is set to async mode !

I'm new to this jQuery. So I beg your pardon for asking this silly question. :)
I have already tried debugging by changing the code and certain other things. But wasn't not successful. That's why I have posted it here.

Thank you...

**Edit:**

jqpost.php code:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['chatuser']))
{

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{

    if(!isset($_POST['usermsg']) || empty($_POST['usermsg'])) 
        exit('Error');

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO chat_tblMsg(m_name , m_uid , m_msg , m_time ) VALUES (? , ? , ? , CONVERT_TZ(NOW(), '-04:00' , '+05:30') )");
    $stmt->bind_param('sss', $_SESSION['chatuser']['uname'], $_SESSION['chatuser']['uid'], trim($_POST['usermsg']));

    /* execute prepared statement */
    $stmt->execute();
    /* close statement and connection */
    $stmt->close();
    /* close connection */
    $mysqli->close();

}
}
```

Comment: can you give jqpost.php please? Perhaps the problem comes from there.

Comment: yeah sure.. edited my first post and have added that code too :)

Comment: I might be misunderstanding this, but are you asking why there is a delay, yet you are intentionally putting usleep() calls in the PHP?

also, what is $sql in the original post? database calls are slow; have you timed how slow the $sql query is?

Comment: I am sorry, I have no idea of what causes the problem. However, you may be interested in making a technology watch of WebSockets ( http://websocket.org/aboutwebsocket.html ). That makes the solution pretty much simpler, improves performance and reduces bandwidth :D . The drawback is that it is still an experimental technology, so incompatible with old browsers.

Comment: @KaeVerens: What I'm using is a longpolling method. So, it would be better than the traditional polling method, which is a continuous polling to the server, which could increase the bandwidth.
So, when the polling is carried out, it would check whether there's any new records. If so, output it. Otherwise, loop for some time until a new message is obtained. The delay is only 0.2 seconds. After that small delay, I'm executing the query to check whether there's any new records. If so, it would exit the loop. Otherwise, the loop is continued.

Comment: @KaeVerens:
I didn't tried checking the time taken for the database calls. Because, there's only about 100 records. And I thought it won't be a matter. But will check it since you mentioned it. :)

The sql is: `SELECT m_name , m_id, m_uid , m_msg , m_time FROM chat_tblMsg WHERE m_id > '$m_id' ORDER BY m_id DESC LIMIT 15`

Thanks :)

Comment: @fflorent: Thanks :)
Yeah the main reason for not using was that still many uses the old browsers. The chat app was mainly for a group of my friends. Some of them are still using IE6 :D
And I have to make some changes to the current CSS code too, because I didn't made it cross browser compatible. :)

Comment: @AkhileshBChandran IE6 O_o ? OK :(

Comment: yeah.. some of them didn't bothered to install any new browsers other than the default IE6 that come with XP ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Is the poll query is holding a database lock, preventing the post query from executing?

What happens if you close your $result before sleeping:

```
while ($wait_current < 20 && $result->num_rows == 0)
{
    if (isset($result))
    {
        $result->close();
    }
    usleep(200000); // 0.2 seconds
    $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
    $wait_current = time() - $wait_start;
}
```

Comment: Thanks... But that's also not having much effect :(